# How to return a typed list from a method with the Eclipse EMF?

Tags: eclipse, emf, eclipse-emf

I would like to generate define generically typed return parameters in an EMF model.

The current state of the model is similar as the example in the following image.

[image: EMF Example class]

Is it even possible to alter the model that it generates the interface code for our example class as depicted below? And if so, how do I do that?

```
/**
 * ...
 * @generated
 */
public interface Example extends EObject {
    /**
     * ...
     * @generated
     */
    List<Definition> getDefinitions();      

    /**
     * ...
     * @generated
     */
    Optional<Extension> getExtension();      

}
```

Btw. the classes Definition and Extension are modelled within the same diagram.

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new "EData Type", e.g. "MyList", where the "Instance Type Name" is e.g. `java.util.List<my.fully.qualified.name.Definition>`.